# Which Scriptures mention "Chitrahuti" (चित्राहुति) or "Chitravati" procedure which we carry out before starting of our meals?

Tags: scripture, culture, tradition, food

**Chitrahuti (चित्राहुति)** Or "Chitravati", is a procedure of keeping small amount of food out side of the plate on the floor  , as offering to "Chitra ,Chitragupta and Yama (चित्रा , चित्रगुप्त , यम)  and the gods who govern elements of nature , before starting of our meals.

My questions are -:

1) In which  Scriptures of Hinduism this Chitrahuti  procedure is mentioned?

2) Are their  any puranic stories associated with this Chitrahuti procedure?

Answer (score 5):

The detail procedure of Chitrahuti is described in book named
"**Shukla Yajuhu Shkhieya Nitya BrahmaKarmaSamucchaya."
(शुक्लयजु:शाखीय नित्यब्रह्मकर्म समुच्चय:) in Bhojan Prayoga.(भोजन प्रयोग)** .This procedure is also described in the  same book for followers of Rig-veda.i.e.**Rig veda Nitya** **BrahmaKarmaSamucchaya**.So the exact mantra's depends on the Veda and shakha (branch of respective veda) that one is following.

The entire procedure involves reciting of various mantras and suktas like "**Trisuparna Sukta**" from Rig-Veda.Its bit lengthy so i am giving only the Chitrahuti part and mantras from the book in answer,which is for Shulka Yajur Veda followers.

> अग्रिममंत्रत्रयेण भोजनपात्राद् घृताक्तमोदनं गृहीत्वा
>   पात्राद्दक्षिणभागे भूमौ प्राक् संस्था उदक् संस्था वा
>   बदरीफलप्रमाणास्तिस्त्र आहुतयो देया:॥  ॐ भूपतये स्वाहा नमः ।ॐ भुवनपतये
>   स्वाहा नमः । ॐ भूतानां पतये स्वाहा नमः
>
> AgniMantraTrayena BhojanPatrad GhrutaktaModanam Gruhitva
>   PatraddDakshinBhage Bhumao Prak Sanstha Udak Sanstha Va
>   BadariPhalaPramana stistra Ahutayo Deya. Om Bhupataye Swaha Namaha *Om
>   Bhuvanpataye Swaha Namaha* Om Bhutanam Pataye Swaha Namaha
>
> **Meaning** - In the plate by mixing Rice with Ghee of size of indian plum , give three Ahuties (offerings) by above mantras to LeftEast or
>   North side of the plate.

[image]

Comment: Hari om. Can you please guide how is the bali to be done? Are we to consume the food when giving the traya bali? e.g., om bhū
pataye svāhā | do we leave the Āhutis in a corner outside the plate (which is to be thrown later or do we consume it after saying the mantra?

Comment: Yes , its quite simple. We just have to keep three seprate portions of the food either in the plate or outside. Sprinkling water around them three times as we generally do while offering naivaidyam ,with the mantra "Om Bhuvanpataye Swaha Namaha Om Bhutanam Pataye Swaha Namaha".We don't have to consume that portion , it has to be kept out side along with dish. Generally the banana leaf was used as a dish previously so with that it was easy to roll up the leaf and keep it outside.But a  now since we use metal and other dishes ,we simply can keep the portion outside after food.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, Thanks for your nice answer. I was looking for the same. Can you pl share the soft copy of full ebook शुक्लयजु:शाखीय नित्यब्रह्मकर्म समुच्चय: and/or "Trisuparna Sukta"? I am a Yajurvedi brahmin. Thanks. (if anybody else is having the soft copy, request to pl. share it).

Comment: @Vineet Very thanks for your encouragement. Yes , I will try to scan that book and will convert into PDF and will share it with you. But it will take sometime , will definitely update you.

Comment: @Vineet - Sorry actually , there is some problem with my scanner , so instead of scanned book i will post direct screenshots of the book in the chat room "https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy" - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, sorry for my late reply. I checked those links. They just take me to the chat room. I think the screenshots are yet to be posted.

Comment: @Vineet - Yes , I will , surely &  will  tell you after that. :-)