# Do the scriptures talk about procedures that a Brahmin has to do before eating food?

Tags: scripture, brahmins, food

What are the procedures that a Brahmin has to follow before having food. I have seen the process of sprinkling water, but what is the whole process? What is the mantra one has to chant at that time?

Comment: If so kindly link it! Because before asking this question, in the list of already asked questions, it was missing! So I asked! @Rickross

Comment: Okay I found this one: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/should-we-chant-mantras-before-eating-food/3286#3286

Comment: Is that Q same as urs? but I could not find Swiftpushkar's answer there but I remember reading one such answer from him

Comment: @Rickross What about process we should do?? because aside mantras, i have seen certain people do some process before eating and then chant mantra

Comment: Yes it's sprinkling water around the plate .. besides that 5 Grasa Mantras ( Pranaya swaha, apanaya swaha etc ) are also chanted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we chant mantras before eating food?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3241/should-we-chant-mantras-before-eating-food) and [Which Scriptures mention “Chitrahuti” (चित्राहुति) or “Chitravati” procedure which we carry out before starting of our meals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14765/5212). This process is called Parishechana.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma - thanks. Second one Chitravati procedure was one I was looking for than mantras..... !!