# Why do we put water around plate before eating in the process Chitrahuti (चित्राहुति) Or "Chitravati"?

Tags: culture, food, customs

I have checked the following Q&A which addressed about this ritul in the past.

[Which Scriptures mention "Chitrahuti" (चित्राहुति) or "Chitravati" procedure which we carry out before starting of our meals?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14765/which-scriptures-mention-chitrahuti-%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF-or-chitravati-procedure-whi) although they look like dupe, my question is different.

I also googled about Chitrahuti and found the meaning as below, the [link](https://www.hindujagruti.org/explandict/chitrahuti)

> chitrahuti a portion of food set aside as an offering to God, before the commencement of a meal
>
> Pronunciation ‘chitrâhutî’

**My specific question is why do we put water droplets around the plate and then place the food.**

Comment: that is called prokshnam this whole process  vishwanara yagna this food should first should be offered to God risiding inside for that purification starts with prokshanam.. there is practice to eat food in floor.. so ant like insects will brage in while eating because of sweats or other aroma to prevent that this is done..

Comment: @PrasannaR You can write up an answer with the details you have sinc you also mention the process name of Vishwanara yagna.

Comment: I don't have scriptual reference it's daily practice as stated in Vedas all Brahmanas will do